# Position Fixed element causing entire page to repaint/redraw

Tags: html, css, positioning

I've got a page that is very image heavy along with lots of CSS3 transitions. I've also got a nav bar at the top of the page that's the full width of the viewport, with position fixed. When scrolling the page it is VERY sluggish. From what I can tell, the nav is a major culprit in causing the repaints and or redraws.

Are there any techniques to minimize this?

Comment: What transitions and animations are on the nav? Could you provide us with some code? It's hard to help on so little information :(

Answer (score 0):

There are some tips and tricks by Nicole Sullivan to mitigate these problems here:

http://www.stubbornella.org/content/2009/03/27/reflows-repaints-css-performance-making-your-javascript-slow/